# Is there a way to reverse my vote on whether to "close" a question or not?

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-close

I was reviewing some questions and voting on whether they should be "closed" or not, and I accidentally pressed "Leave Open" on one I certainly meant to vote "close" ([Am I Concussed?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/11047/am-i-concussed)). **Can I alter/edit my vote? Or is it set in stone?**

I tried to go back-one-page in a desperate attempt to edit my vote, but I couldn't figure it out. Sorry to bother you with such a question that I'm sure is probably easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.

A "leave open" vote isn't really a vote, it's a way of signalling to the site's software that you don't think this question should be reviewed for potential closure.  If enough "leave open" votes are cast, the question will be removed from the "close votes" queue, but you or anyone else can still vote to close it by visiting the question and clicking on the "close" link below the question.

Voting "close", on the other hand, really is a vote.  You can still retract it, though, by visiting the question, clicking on the "close" link, and selecting the "retract close vote" button.

Comment: Good to know! I've been wondering this myself!